# Field extension of Rational functions

Tags: field-theory

I have a homework question where I have to find $$\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3+x+1)$$ and represent elements 1/a, 1/(1+a) and 1/(1+a^2) as a polynomial in a. Where a is the image of x in $$\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3+x+1)$$ I understand the main idea of field extensions but I'm not too sure what to do with the polynomial above in order to be able to answer the question. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If $f(x)u(x) +g(x)v(x) =1$ (Bezout identity) then $f(x)u(x) = 1$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(g(x))$

Answer (score 1):

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3+x+1)$. Then $K=\mathbb{Q}[a]$ with $a^3+a+1=0$.

Therefore, $a(a^2+1)=-1$. This gives $\frac1a = -(a^2+1)$ and $\frac1{a^2+1}=-a$.

To find $\frac1{a+1}$, note that every element in $K$ is a quadratic expression in $a$. So, you may try to solve $(a+1)(Aa^2+Ba+C)=1$ for $A,B,C$. I'd start with $A=C=1$.

Comment: $a+1= - a^3$ and you know the inverse of $a$.

Comment: @orangeskid, of course!

Comment: @Ihf ok that makes sense! Thanks a lot!

Comment: $$ 1 = a^3+a+2 = (a+1)(a^2-a+2)$$ implies $$\frac{1}{a+1} = a^2-a+2$$